# (Speed Challenge) Any faster way to compute distance matrix in terms of generic Hamming distance?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, matrix, hamming-distance

I am looking for a more efficient way to get the distance matrix in terms of [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

**Backgrounds**

I know there is a function `hamming.distance()` from package `e1071` to compute the distance matrix, but I suspect it might be very slow when involving a large matrix with many rows, since it applied nested `for` loops for computation.

So far I have a faster way (see `methodB`) in the code below. However, it is only suitable for in the binary domain, i.e., `{0,1}^n`. However, it is unavailable when encountering domains consisting of more than 2 elements, i.e., `{0,1,2,...,K-1}^n`. In this sense, `methodB` is not for generic hamming distance.

**Objective**

My objective is to find a approach having the following features:

- composed by functions only from base R (not using `Rcpp` to rewrite function for speeding up)
- faster than my approach `methodB()` for the special case `k=2`
- can be generalized for any positive integer `k`
- outperform the speed of `hamming.distance()` from package `e1071`

**My code**

```
library(e1071)
# vector length, i.e., number of matrix
n <- 7
# number of elements to consist of domain {0,1,...,k-1}^n
k <- 2
# matrix for computing hamming distances by rows
m <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid,replicate(n,list(0:k-1))))

# applying `hamming.distance()` from package "e1071", which is generic so it is available for any positive integer `k`
methodA <- function(M) hamming.distance(M)
# my customized method from base R function `dist()`, which is not available for cases `k >= 2`
methodB <- function(M) as.matrix(round(dist(M,upper = T,diag = T)**2))
```

and the benchmark gives

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  methodA(m),
  methodB(m),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equivalent",
  times = 50
)

Unit: relative
       expr      min       lq   mean   median       uq      max neval
 methodA(m) 33.45844 33.81716 33.963 34.30313 34.92493 14.92111    50
 methodB(m)  1.00000  1.00000  1.000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    50
```

Appreciated in advance!

Comment: This might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942412/find-the-hamming-distance-between-string-sequences#comment106005537_59942412

Comment: @chinsoon12 thanks for the information, I will have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
methodM <- function(x) {
  xt <- t(x)
  sapply(1:nrow(x), function(y) colSums(xt != xt[, y]))
}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  methodB(m), methodM(m),
  unit = "relative", check = "equivalent", times = 50
)
# Unit: relative
#       expr  min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# methodB(m) 1.00 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50  a 
# methodM(m) 1.25 1.224827 1.359573 1.219507 1.292463 4.550159    50   b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, your method is fast and can be extended to cases where `k>2`. Do you have any idea that is faster than my `methodB()` for the special case `k = 2`?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding it isn't faster probably because doesn't use low level, optimized function `dist`. Also this calculates all distances, ideal we would want to use better algorithm that calculates the values only for upper(lower) triangular part.

Comment: yes, I see, maybe what we have is already the speed limit of using base R

Answer (score 3):

I found this blog which has four posts on calculcating Hamming Matrixes. I don't want to claim any fame for it, but maybe have a look at it.
https://johanndejong.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/faster-hamming-distance-in-r-2/

```
hamming <- function(X) {
  D <- (1 - X) %*% t(X)
  D + t(D)
}

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   methodB(m),
+   hamming(m),
+   unit = "relative",
+   times = 50
+ )
Unit: relative
       expr    min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 methodB(m) 1.0000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50
 hamming(m) 1.2502 1.299844 1.436486 1.301461 1.302033 4.607748    50
```

PS: I don't have enough reputation to just leave this as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `Rcpp`? I had a very similar problem! Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067825/3237589

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use base R (instead of `Rcpp`), as stated in my post