# Find the Hamming distance between string sequences

Tags: r, arrays, string, vectorization, hamming-distance

I have a dataset of 3156 DNA sequences, each of which has 98290 characters (SNPs), comprising the (usual) 5 symbols : **A, C, G, T, N** (gap).

**What is the optimal way to find the pairwise Hamming distance between these sequences?**

*Note that for each sequence, I actually want to find the reciprocal of the number of sequences (including itself), where the per-site hamming distance is less than some threshold (0.1 in this example).*

So far, I have attempted the following:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=8)
result <- foreach(i = 1:3156) %dopar% {
 temp <- 1/sum(sapply(snpdat, function(x) sum(x != snpdat[[i]])/98290 < 0.1))
}
```

`snpdat` is a `list` variable where `snpdat[[i]]` contains the `i`th DNA sequence.

This takes around 36 minutes to run on a core i7 - 4790 with 16GB ram. 
I also tried using the `stringdist` package, which takes more time to generate the same result.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: a quick google came up with this: https://johanndejong.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/fast-hamming-distance-in-r/

Comment: You might consider using specialized functions, such as `dist.hamming` in `phangorn`, or the `Biostrings` package on Bioconductor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 
@GordonShumway, my dataset is unforutnately too large for matrix multiplication...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @Axeman, I will give it a shot now...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the most optimal solution, but I was able to bring the run time down to around 15 minutes using Rcpp. I'll write the code here in case someone might find it useful someday...

This is the C++ code (I have used [Sugar](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) operators here)...

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

double test5(const List& C, const int& x){
  double HD;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3156; i++) if(sum(CharacterVector(C[x])!=CharacterVector(C[i])) < 9829) HD++;
  return HD;
}
```

After compiling:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("hd_code.cpp")
```

I simply call this function from R:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 8)
t =Sys.time()
bla = foreach(i = 1:3156, .combine = "c") %dopar% test5(snpdat,i-1)
Sys.time() - t
```

Can anyone think of an even quicker way to do this?